# JSoup selector not returning result

Tags: css-selectors, jsoup

I have used JSoup in the past and have been able to convert XPaths to Selectors, but I can't get the result for this one table on a site that has changed.

I'm trying to retrieve the Standings table from [this Georgia soccer site](http://gs-fall15athenaandclassic.sportsaffinity.com/tour/public/info/schedule_results2.asp?sessionguid=&flightguid=CB37D3C7-5EF7-4CCE-8918-3AC3083495A3&tournamentguid=173EB212-BADB-425F-BE03-D05CA448AD8D).

From Chrome, I get the selector for the tbody of the table as `#tabs-1 > div > table:nth-child(12) > tbody > tr > td > table:nth-child(1) > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > table > tbody`.

Firefox gives a similar selector for the table `.placeholder > table:nth-child(12) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > table:nth-child(1)`

Neither works.  Even at the [Try JSoup link](https://try.jsoup.org/)

The first nth-child table itself `#tabs-1 > div > table:nth-child(12)` returns null.

Any idea what's so special about this page?

I set the user agent string to `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36`

Comment: It seems try jsoup is parsing the HTML differently than how a browser would. Based on the DOM that is seen in both browsers, there is quite clearly a `#tabs-1 > div > table:nth-child(12)`. The page is riddled with errors, so I wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: I have reported an issue (https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/705) to Jsoup team on github.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have found a bug in Jsoup. However, here is a workaround for extracting the table:

```
table#Table6 + table > tbody:has(tr.theadb)
```

[DEMO](http://try.jsoup.org/~rHxJqYO5mK_REFCt-UgoOJWH7to)

Answer (score 0):

i think the info you need is in the tr tags with the class name tbody0 &  tbody1. you may try out this.

```
public static void main (String []args) throws IOException {
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://gs-fall15athenaandclassic.sportsaffinity.com/tour/public/info/schedule_results2.asp?sessionguid=&flightguid=CB37D3C7-5EF7-4CCE-8918-3AC3083495A3&tournamentguid=173EB212-BADB-425F-BE03-D05CA448AD8D").get();
 Elements ele = doc.select("tr.tbody0,tr.tbody1");

 for(Element e : ele){
     System.out.println(e.text()+",");        
 }
 }
```